# Is there a ways of reading data from plot?

Tags: algorithm, plot, complex-numbers

*I am wondering if there is a way to read in data directly from a plot, stored in a PDF or TIFF, rather than reading the data from a binary or text file.*

What I am hoping to do is write a function that can convert complex numbers between their Cartesian and Polar representations.

I require no help with the rest of the algorithm, and I would like to make the input and output as elegant as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general no, not easily or reliably.  And absolutely not with any method that you could call elegant.

A plot in a PDF might be made with vector graphics, which you could in theory turn back into an equation to modify and re-plot.  It would be relative to the page, not the graph axes, though.

OTOH, it might just be a bitmap, like TIFF always is.  Then your input function/library would have to measure pixel positions in the bitmap.  Either way, you'd have to match them up with the graph axes.

Comment: Thank you very much. That helps me greatly.

Comment: @Darth_Malloc: if you think it's a good enough answer, you should mark it as "accepted", with the checkbox under the up/down vote arrows.

Comment: Thanks! I am new here. Sorry about that.